# Recommendations Bar not posting 'read' items to timeline

Tags: facebook, facebook-social-plugins, facebook-opengraph

I have seen various posts about the add-to-timeline social plugin being 'broken', however have any of you managed to get the  to work?

With the og:type set to article the plugin was marking posts as 'read' but they were not appearing anywhere in the timeline, news-ticker or news feed.

I added 
    prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# otilogin: http://ogp.me/ns/apps/otilogin#"
to the opening  tag, as seen in the HTML examples on the Tutorial.

This did not fix the problem.

Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated.

(If you wish to check the source or run an article through the debug tool here is an example article's address: http://www2.onthisisland.com/driving-cypriot/2010/11/06/)